# URLEncode in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, error-handling, errordocument

I'm trying to make an error document show what page you were trying to go to, but am having issues as it does not escape characters by default (as ecpected)

Most solutions I've seen are to use RewriteRule, but I really do not want to do that, as I want the same document to handle many errors. My current solution is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/Error/Error?c=404&p=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But that would break apart incases such as "example.com/NotExist&=&^72*(238"
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: An absolute URL is wrong to begin with here. With that, you will create an _external redirect_ to this URL, and by that you will lose the 404 status code for the originally requested URL. Use a relative URL, and inside whatever script your are triggering, get the originally requested URL from the server/environment variables.

Comment: With a relative URL, it ends up going to the sub directory's 404 page(i.e. /Dir1/Error/Error vs /Error/Error), which doesn't exist. I want each directory to have a universal error page. I don't want to have a bunch of .htaccess files either because that's just messy.

Comment: Use a URL starting with a slash, so that it is relative to the domain root.

Comment: I already tried:

ErrorDocument 404 /Error/Error

but it does what I described where it uses the subdirectory rather than domain root

Comment: Explain what you mean by “ends up going to the sub directory's 404 page” then. Are you talking about an external redirect here?

Comment: I'm not sure how to, but you'd for instance have the base directory "/", and an error page in "/Error/Error.php". "ErrorDocument 404 /Error/Error" would work if you had an error looking for /NonExistent.php, but if you go to /AnotherDir/NonExistent.php, it'd go to "/AnotherDir/Error/Error.php" rather than "/Error/Error.php". This is with or without the / when defining the ErrorDocument path